# How to align nested column to another div?

Tags: html, css

When you hover above the second item, the hide show under the second item.

What I want:
The "hide" shows under the **FIRST** item, left aligned.

Is that possible even it stays nested with the second one?

Tried it with `margin-left: -30px` and it works, but its not responsive. Is there any solution how i can make it responsive, too?

Thanks for any help!!

Thanks for any help!!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relativ;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.item:hover .hide {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="item">item
      </div>
   <div class="item">item
     <div class="hide">hide</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/Liskari/pen/yLjepRr

Comment: Your html seem incomplete. Also the codepen doesn't seem to reproduce your issue. Please update the stack snippet with a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can position it absolute against the container to achieve this. For this to work you need to remove `position: relative` from the `.item` class. Otherwise the absolute positioning would work relative to the `.item`. Instead you want to add `position: relative` to `.container`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.item:hover .hide {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="item">item
    </div>
   <div class="item">item
     <div class="hide">hide</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```